Interference from ceiling fan light with my wire FM radio antenna
When I turn on my ceiling fan LED light it interferes with my FM radio wire antenna, so I used normal copper wire soldered to the wire antenna and extended to my window about 1meter long. It was better but I still have interference. What can I do?
Should I use shielded wire to solder on the wire antenna and extend?

It only interferes when I turn on my fan light.

Rasul - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was actually more info, not a solution, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Since you asked the question, then unless you are writing the full & final answer to your own question (i.e. unless you don't need further help & you have solved the problem yourself using a different solution than any other answer) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, to add clarification or more info, please [edit] the question (unless that would invalidate an answer). || Please see the [tour] & [help].

It must have very fast X ns risetime and could be switching above AM radio rates of 1.4 MHz but with harmonics reaching 100 MHz.
Suggestion

add 10 nF Y caps across L-N of fan.
add 100 MHz rated ferrite clamps around LED single or wire pairs to remove Vdm or  Vcm noise radiation.
add a diode and LC filter to the LEDs.

I can't know what you understand.
Who made this noisy fan?

The fan is ok. Only when i turn the light on my fan there is interference with my fm radio

Yes I understood that.  I assume they are together. Same question, who made it? model?
